# Software to 'sketch' graphs

Tags: gratis, graphs, drawing

I'm looking for free Windows software or a web app that lets me compose simple graphs with a 'sketch' style, as if drawn freehand. I want to use them to illustrate points made in a text (blog).

Requirements:

- Color, maybe styles
- Be able to put some ticks/data points on the axis
- Different graph types (lines, bars); 2D is good enough
- Ability to add some text in the same style (although that can probably be done later in any image editor)
- Free to publish the graphs, a small corner logo/watermark would be OK
- I would primarily use it 'freehand draw' a graph, but maybe actual data input that generates the graph will come in handy too

Some examples I found doing a Google image search for 'sketch graph':

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 13):

[Python](http://www.python.org) with [numpy](http://numpy.org) and [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) will let you rapidly draw a wide range of graphs and includes an [xkcd plotting style](http://matplotlib.org/examples/showcase/xkcd.html), *(based on [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/) cartoons).*

All of the above are:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform

To cover your requirements:

- Color, maybe styles ***Colour definitely***
- Be able to put some ticks/data points on the axis ***No Problem***
- Different graph types (lines, bars); 2D is good enough ***The XKCD style can be applied to just about any of the matplotlib 2D & 3D graph types you can even have 2/3D animated plots***
- Ability to add some text in the same style (although that can probably be done later in any image editor) ***It is there already.***
- Free to publish the graphs, a small corner logo/watermark would be OK ***Completely free, no logo or watermark unless you choose to add one.***
- I would primarily use it 'freehand draw' a graph, but maybe actual data input that generates the graph will come in handy too ***No freehand but you can very quickly plug in rough sample data.*** *note that you can also use python to query web, database, file or physical sources*

Note that you can save your plots as png, eps, jpeg, pdf, pgf, ps, svg, tiff, etc.

### Example code

Demo from the gallery

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

with plt.xkcd():
    # Based on "Stove Ownership" from XKCD by Randall Monroe
    # http://xkcd.com/418/

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_axes((0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7))
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    ax.set_ylim([-30, 10])

    data = np.ones(100)
    data[70:] -= np.arange(30)

    plt.annotate(
        'THE DAY I REALIZED\nI COULD COOK BACON\nWHENEVER I WANTED',
        xy=(70, 1), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->'), xytext=(15, -10))

    plt.plot(data)

    plt.xlabel('time')
    plt.ylabel('my overall health')
    fig.text(
        0.5, 0.05,
        '"Stove Ownership" from xkcd by Randall Monroe',
        ha='center')

    # Based on "The Data So Far" from XKCD by Randall Monroe
    # http://xkcd.com/373/

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_axes((0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.7))
    ax.bar([-0.125, 1.0 - 0.125], [0, 100], 0.25)
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
    ax.set_xticks([0, 1])
    ax.set_xlim([-0.5, 1.5])
    ax.set_ylim([0, 110])
    ax.set_xticklabels(['CONFIRMED BY\nEXPERIMENT', 'REFUTED BY\nEXPERIMENT'])
    plt.yticks([])

    plt.title("CLAIMS OF SUPERNATURAL POWERS")

    fig.text(
        0.5, 0.05,
        '"The Data So Far" from xkcd by Randall Monroe',
        ha='center')

plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

It even works with 3D plots as shown in the development process on [this ticket](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/1329/):
[image]

Comment: Mmmmm, I'm not particularly happy with learning yet another programming language, but I can see that this gives me a wide range of control.

Comment: @Jan, It's Python, not some random jargon. You likely already know it. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto From his comment, he likely does not.

Comment: @Jeremy, OP asked for a solution to plot data. One has to do some work to get it done. In Italy we say "you can't have a jar full  of wine and a drunk wife at the same time".