# Software to sketch diagram like given below

Tags: sketch, design

I would like to ask which software can I use to make such sketches. Please note that I am not looking for draw.io as it does not produce the same output.

[image: gra]

Comment: Are you looking for software that diagrams, or for something that provides the pseudo hand drawn effect?

Comment: Possibly related: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/33642/software-to-sketch-graphs

Comment: Possibly related: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14192/easy-tool-to-sketch-beautiful-network-diagrams

Comment: https://www.istockphoto.com/ has thousands of flowchart symbols available along with some with a "hand drawn" look. It'll cost you money however.

Comment: https://excalidraw.com/ take a look. Not the exact tool, but close!

Answer (score 1):

[Krita](https://krita.org/en/) is a professional free, open source painting program for Windows/Mac/Linux. It is made by artists that want to see affordable art tools for everyone. You can work with photos or scanned images, or start with a blank slate. Krita supports most graphics tablets out of the box.

Krita is different from other graphics design programs in that it has pluggable brush engines, some supporting brush resources like Gimp brush files, others offering sophisticated simulation of real brushes, and others again offering color mixing and image deformations. Moreover, Krita has full support for graphics tablets, including such features as pressure, tilt and rate, making it a great choice for artists. There are easy to use tools for drawing lines, ellipses and rectangles, and the freehand tool is supported by pluggable "drawing assistants" that help you draw shapes that still have a freehand feeling to them.

---

[draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) is a free online diagram software for making flowcharts, process diagrams, org charts, UML, ER and network diagrams. draw.io is available for Windows. Mac and Linux. In many common Linux distribution that support the snap package format the drawio snap package can be installed with this command:

```
sudo snap install drawio
```

With draw.io you don't need to draw anything, just select an object from the left panel and drag it into the canvas. To change colors draw.io has a built-in color picker. In order to make this diagram I enabled the *Network* library which contains the laptop and phone shapes as follows: Click on *More shapes…* at the bottom of the left panel → Scroll down in the *Shapes* dialog to make sure the Network shape library is enabled → Click *Apply*.

[image: Web app]

Comment: I think the OP is looking for something that provides the “sketchy” appearance.

Comment: I asked the OP in a comment. In the meantime, I’d welcome an additional answer with the more more sketchy effect. Sometimes, even in the corporate world, one wants to suggest the presented info is tentative and an informal look is desired.

Comment: @karel Thank you for your inputs. Yes, I like sketches for my personal blogs as well as for presentations. Please let me know if you have any better solution than draw,io. I currently use the same with comic mode but still it does not come closer to what I have posted above from one of the book I am reading through and author has used this informal (if you think it is) way of drawings to please his reader.

Comment: @EricShain Thank you! You are right that I need better than draw.io, which does not give sketchy look.

Comment: @codebased Thanks for commenting because I didn't know for sure what kind of an app you were looking for. I added my reply to your comment to my answer. I'm a big fan of geometric designs like this ["jungle" image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD1be.jpg) that I created.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's been hand-drawn with a stylus.

If you have an iPad and an Apple Pencil, check the free app "Tayasui Sketches School", for example. The app can produce such graphs, in particular the watercolor effect, in  2 minutes.

Such apps are also available for Android and other OSs too. I think the important part is using a stylus/pencil, and any vendor will suffice.